# Big Sur CMD+Tab, CMD+Space and Backspace keys not working

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur

I'm using Macbook Pro 16 inch 2020. Everything works correctly when I bought it. Later then I upgraded to BigSur then I started to get strange keyboard problems. All keys working but **CMD+Tab**, **CMD+Space** and **Backspace** keys not working. But **CMD+A** (select all shortcut) is working and then **Backspace** is deleting all text. But **Backspace** not working without **CMD+A**. Yes this is so strange but I don't know the reason and I don't have any idea for this.

I'm using **AltTab** program (https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) and I doubt from it but may be I'm wrong. Do you have any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: The quick test would be to uninstall AltTab & see what happens.

Comment: I did it. Not affected anything. I restarted the computer. But there must be solution except restart the whole system.

Comment: So after removing AltTab and restarting the problem is gone?

Comment: I didn't remove. Reinstalled and restarted then problem is gone but I know it will accour again.